# Click Event not being Fired in fixed position footer on iphone/ipad

Tags: javascript, html, ios

So i'm having some difficulty with a click event within a page being rendered on iphone/ipad. This works propery in all desktop browsers i have checked as well as within android. The issue lies with clicking on the LIs in the footer. I have attempted to attach a click event to the footer elements via the following:

```
$('#footer li').live('click', function(e) { 

        Site.loadpage($(this).attr('page') + '.html');

});
```

But nothing happens (no javascript errors or anything). So to get more information i added a more generic click event, where perhaps i would find some other element getting in the way that is capturing the event with this:

```
$('*').live('click', function(e) { 

    alert(e.target);

});
```

With this event, i can click anywhere on my page and i get an alert with the type of element i have clicked on. **EXCEPT for in the footer**, where nothing at all happening.

Here is some further information about the page i am using this with, i can provide more information if necessary, the only other thing that may be relevant is that i am using jquery for this (obviously).

I have a page with the following structure:

```
<body>
        <div id="header">

        </div>

        <div id="content">

        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <ul>
                <li page="projects" class="projects"><span>Projects</span></li>
                <li page="people" class="people active"><span>People</span></li>    
                <li page="assignments" class="assignments"><span>Assignments</span></li>
                <li page="search" class="search"><span>Search</span></li>
                <li page="more" class="more"><span>More</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
```

And the following CSS:

```
html { 

    height:100%; 
    width: 100%;
    margin:0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 0px; 
    position: fixed;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
}

body { 

    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

#header { 

    background: url(../images/devices/iphone/header.jpg); 
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 45px; /* ADJUST FOR IPAD */
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 4px 7px #888;
}

#header .center { 

    position: static;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 45px; /* ADJUST FOR IPAD */
    text-align: center;

}

#header h1.center { margin: 8px 0px 10px 0px; }

#content { 

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 48px;
    top: 45px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;



}

#footer { 

    background: url(../images/devices/iphone/header.jpg);
    background-size: 48px 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 48px; /* ADJUST FOR IPAD */
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer { text-align: center; }
#footer ul { list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 1px; font-size: 8px; }
#footer li { padding-top: 35px; padding-bottom: 1px; display: inline-block; background-image: url(../images/inactive-menu.png); width: 62px; background-size: 312px; }
#footer li.active { background-image: url(../images/active-menu.png); }
#footer li span { width: 57px; padding-top: 10px; }
#footer li.projects { background-position: 0px 0px;}
#footer li.people { background-position: -62px 0px;}
#footer li.assignments { background-position: -124px 0px;}
#footer li.search { background-position: -187px 0px;}
#footer li.more { background-position: -250px 0px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe live works in iOS for some reason. Try .on() , that should work.

```
$('*').on('click', function(e) { 

    alert(e.target);

});
```

Comment: Hrmm, I am using live elsewhere in my application and it appears to be working properly on other elements it is only the footer that is giving me the problem. I would like to avoid using "on" if i can, as the footer within my application can be set dynamically, and if i can bind the event once and im good to go for the entire session that would be ideal. That being said, for now I have changed it to use your method after the footer is built on each page loads and it is working properly. Unless some one comes up with a diff answer i will give you the points.

Comment: I see your reasoning, .on() might not be 100% what you want, but as of jQuery 1.7 the .live() method was deprecated so that might be part of your issue. Also this seems to be a known bug in jQuery http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10546

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. Tried to alert events on this footer element no luck. By accident I tried:

```
$('*').on('touchend', function(e) {});
```

Please note I am using 'touchend' as my triggering event and also have set:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Tested on iPhone 3GS, iOS 5.1.1.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the touch events rather than the click event, which is a mouse event, not a touchscreen event -
touchstart and touchend make more sense as a touchscreen event

Comment: ive tried click, vclick and touch and all of them met with the same result.

Comment: just a shot in the dark, but you can try giving a positioning attribute (e.g. position:relative) and a z-index that is >0.
maybe iOs renders footer with a lesser z-index

Comment: just re-read your css, is the display:none on the footer really there in your source?

Comment: blah my mistake in including that, that should not be there. also i tried the z-index thing, thats why i tried using the binding on all elements in the first place to try and capture something that may be on top of it yet hidden, but no dice.